# Angular 4: How to handle cascading changes?

Tags: angular

I have a small app [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/BmDskTa3BgG6m4Wnd2pq).

**What it does**: It has 3 dropdowns which represent something like address selection - district, municipality and settlement. They are dependent on each other so what gets selected in one dropdown dictates the items in the next dropdown. There is a root component which passes 3 input number values to the child component (I added also some delay to simulate http call).

**My goal**: To be able to update immediately the values in the root component, whenever something changes in the child component (in AngularJS 1 we had the `=` option for the child directive scope). That's why I used two-way binding for the properties, you can see that I have to emit whenever something changes. I also want to pass the data as simple number properties, instead of binding the child component to some custom class with the 3 properties.

**The problems I'm facing**:
1) I have to manually emit through `EventEmitter<numner>` whenever something changes (since I have 3 simple-type properties). **We didn't have to do that in AngularJS 1, so is there a more flexible solution than that?**
2) The app you're seeing works, because I added a call to `enableProdMode` in my `main.ts` file. That's because I need to violate the unidirectional flow rule of NG4+: this happens when a value in one dropdown changes, then I need to set the dependent value to null and update the items in the dependent dropdown in the OnChanges hook (e.g. when I change district, municipality has to be nullified). **Is there a better approach to do this or it's ok to violate the rule knowing what you are doing?**

Answer (score 1):

i have two dropdowns in my app that also that are depend on each other. I use reactive form and subscribe to value changes:

```
slots$: Observable<Array<SlotIdentity>>;


ngOnInit(): void {
  this.buildRoleForm();

  this.slots$ = this.formGroup.get('pageId')
    .valueChanges
    .map(pageId => _.sortBy(this.pages.find(({id}) => id === +pageId).slots, 'slotNumber'))
   .do(() => this.formGroup.get('slotId').setValue(''));
}

private buildRoleForm() {
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  pageId: ['', Validators.required],
  slotId: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

}

html is here:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" novalidate>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="pageNumber" col-sm-6>Page#</label>
      <select id="pageNumber" class="form-control" formControlName="pageId">
        <option *ngFor="let page of pages" value="{{page.id}}">
          {{page.pageNumber}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="slotNumber">Slot#</label>
      <select id="slotNumber" class="form-control" formControlName="slotId">
        <option *ngFor="let slot of slots$ | async" value="{{slot.id}}">
          {{slot.slotNumber}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't know Reactive Forms in detail, but that's an interesting example.

Answer (score 0):

first of all I would not keep three separate numbers, but instead create some wrapper for it (let's call it `wrapper` for a moment - keep in mind the from Rest call you should receive one object with fields)

```
export class Wrapper {
    districtId: number;
    municipalityId: number;
    settlementId: number;
    constructor(dist, mun, sett){
      this.districtId = dist;
      this.municipalityId = mun;
      this.settlementId = sett;
    }
}
```

then our app.html will look like:

```
District id: {{ wrapper.districtId }}
Minicipality id: {{ wrapper.municipalityId }}
Settlement id: {{ wrapper.settlementId }}

<my-child [wrapper]="wrapper"></my-child>
```

note that each change of the fields will automatically be visible on `wrapper.districtId` etc.

the we can simplify our child component:
As we input `wrapper` object, we cannot base our logic on OnChanges() (as it would be called once the reference to `wrapper` object changes, and in our case only fields are updated), but we can call particular functions on `select` change:

```
<div>
    <label for="district">District</label>
    <select id="district" (change)="setMunicipalities()" [(ngModel)]="wrapper.districtId">
        <option [value]="district.id" *ngFor="let district of districts">{{ district.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and the final logic. Note that when we call setMunicipalities() we do not need to check if anything changed, note that we do not have extra checks what was changed (as previously)

```
constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        this.districts = DISTRICTS;
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.setMunicipalities();
  this.setSettlements();
}    


private setMunicipalities() {
  this.municipalities = MUNICIPALITIES.filter(mun => mun.districtId == this.wrapper.districtId);
  this.setSettlements();

  this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}

private setSettlements(){
  this.settlements = SETTLEMENTS.filter(sett => sett.municipalityId == this.wrapper.municipalityId);
}
```

i forked your plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/A7aGJcZhQAryvVPLTrOA?p=preview) - i had problems with injecting ChangeDetectorRef in plunker (so not all the dropdowns are automatically updated, but hope you got the feeling how it should work)

Comment: Ok, so I added another fork here: https://plnkr.co/edit/xIdEx1m3HWxMn9aLTdk1?p=preview. I'm not using ChangeDetectorRef, but it works fine. Why did you want to inject it? Note that I still have some logic for nullification of dependent values which uses 2 flags - otherwise I can't know if the changes are coming from OnChanges (needed when there is a delay like in the example) or from the change event of the dropdown (in which case I really need to nullify the value). Just to guide you through the example, all of the components that are actually used in the fork have 2 in the name.

Comment: I wanted to use ChangeDetectorRef to trigger manually changes on the screen (but it works without it, nice). I do not find a real use case of those flags you proposed. In the case on plunker, the only corner case is the initialization of child component when you do not have yet AddressInfo which you got covered in OnChanges block. Then you can execute setMunicipalities(), update municipalities and set this.address.municipalityId to null, always, and proceed to setSettlements(). When you enter setMunicipalities(), you should always clear dropdown.

Comment: take a look https://plnkr.co/edit/vqgcAkBYXPILCD3iKldc?p=preview on the other hand I propose slightly different solution, let's wait until AddressInfo is resolved from some Rest call, and then render Child component like here: https://plnkr.co/edit/aIBbIpogahc2AIVtg2EQ?p=preview

Comment: I use the flags, because otherwise the municipality and settlement dropdowns get empty values on init (when you have specified everything). You can see in my plunker that everything is filled initially and in yours you only have district. :) For your other plunker - yes, it really makes sense to show another element until the observable completes.